# Sort a dataset based on the order of another

Tags: sas

I have two datasets that look like this:

> ```
>       PATID         Mean           
>       0001          234
>       0004          230
>       0007          237
>       0008          239
>       0010          231
>       ....          ...
> ```

and a second one that looks like this:

> ```
>       PATID         std           
>       0010          4.1
>       0008          5.9
>       0007          6.8
>       0001          1.1
>       0004          12.9
>       ....          ...
> ```

Is there a way to sort the second dataset by PATID with the order of PATID of the first? Although not all are shown for simplicity, the two datasets have the same PATIDs although in a different order.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing `PATID` is a character variable given the leading 0's.
A simple `proc sort` should do the trick

```
data have;
infile datalines;
input patid $4. std :8.;
datalines;
0010 4.1
0008 5.9
0007 6.8
0001 1.1
0004 12.9
;
```

```
proc sort data=have out=want; by patid; quit;
```

```
patid std
0001  1.1
0004  12.9
0007  6.8
0008  5.9
0010  4.1
```

---

Should dataset one not be sorted in an ascending order, you could create the sequence order and left join

```
data have1;
infile datalines;
input patid $4. mean :8.;
datalines;
0001 234
0007 237
0004 230
0010 231
0008 239
;

data have2;
infile datalines;
input patid $4. std :8.;
datalines;
0010 4.1
0008 5.9
0007 6.8
0001 1.1
0004 12.9
;

data have1_view / view=have1_view;
set have1;
seq=_n_;
run;

proc sql;
    create table want as
    select t1.patid, t2.std
    from have1_view t1 left join have2 t2
    on t1.patid = t2.patid
    order by seq
    ;
quit;
```

```
patid std
0001  1.1
0007  6.8
0004  12.9
0010  4.1
0008  5.9
```

Comment: Unfortunately I need to do a match!

Comment: If the dataset one is not sorted in an ascending order, can't you just left join dataset one with dataset two? See my edited answer.